# can i delete .repo after repo sync is successfull?

Tags: git, github, android-source

I'm trying to port Lollipop on snapdragon 8074, And i'm running low on disk space.
So i was thinking of deleting the .repo directory after repo sync is successfully done, to make some space for building the source code.

Is it necessary to keep the .repo after the source code is downloaded.?

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest finding something else to delete as the .repo directory is needed if you want to use a lot of the repo command such as `repo diff`. Also if you ever plan to organize your added changes in your own git repositories you will want to edit the `.repo/manifest.xml` or add your own `.repo/local_manifests`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @Wextux , I am aware that the .repo will be needed for future downloads, But was wondering if i could take a backup of .repo and copy it back when needed. And will i be able to build without .repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely move the .repo directory to another location and later restore it if needed. There's nothing special about that directory. If you move it, no Git or Repo commands will work, obviously. As there *may* be Git commands in the makefiles you could experience build failures with an absent .repo directory. I had a quick look in the Lollipop makefiles  and couldn't find any obvious Git command references so there's a decent chance that you'll be okay.

Why one would want to go through this hassle to save a few tens of GB when you need a multi-core multi-GB RAM machine to be able to build is difficult to understand.

Comment: Thank you @Magnus for the reply.  I understand your amusement regarding my situation, But i have done multiple repo syncs lately with different branches, and it consumed 250 GB of my disk space. The last repo sync broke during the sync, so i tried force sync so im worried if the repository is intact. and that left me with 20 GB of free space to build, So i had nothing else to erase which can make a difference.